# mysql query for a value across several columns

Tags: mysql, select

What is a nice way to find records with a null value in a set of columns?  Something kind of like

```
"Select all rows where null IN( col6, col7, col8, col9, col10)"
```

Do I have to do comparisons for each column?

Comment: What is the expected result if (i) one column is not null (ii) all columns are null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where greatest(col6, col7, col8, col9, col10) is null
```

Comment: Clever and effective. This seems to take advantage of the fact that NULL is not greater than or less than any actual value so it comes out on top every time.

Comment: Nice.  I was wondering why `NULL` was always the greatest().  Seems to work the way I want though: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb642c/3

Comment: NULL is not the greatest. The result is just undefined if any parameter is NULL. If the result is undefined, NULL (not a value) will be returned. CONCAT() would also work. And probably some other functions with flexible number of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite elegant, but neither is the db structure that you have to work with.

```
Select all rows where col6 is null or col7 is null or col8 is null or coll9 is null or ...
```